# How can I create a two column or (six) array for storing the results of loop function estimates (n, R^2)?

Tags: python, arrays, validation, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to train random forest with different number of trees from 1 to 50 and validate quality of created random forest using cross validation over 5 blocks with (r2) measure.

I wanted to create an array with two columns (like a table) in the first column I could place number of trees from 1 to 50 and in another I could put r2 measure(s).

I came up with the code:

```
z = np.linspace(1.0, 50.0, num=50) # generate # of trees from 1 to 50
Z = np.array(z)
P_scores = [Z,]
z1 = 1
while z1 < len(Z):
   clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=z1, random_state=1)
   clf.fit(X, Y)
   kf = KFold(len(X), n_folds=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
   R2 = cross_val_score(clf, X, Y, cv=kf, n_jobs=-1, scoring='r2')
   P_scores.append(R2)
   z1 += 1
print(P_scores)
```

However, the results looks far away from what I could expect:

`[array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
        12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,
        23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,  30.,  31.,  32.,  33.,
        34.,  35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.,  40.,  41.,  42.,  43.,  44.,
        45.,  46.,  47.,  48.,  49.,  50.]), array([ 0.18870118,  0.11762437,  0.23292905,  0.01941026, -0.04797139])]`

I expected at least that the array with r2 term would be longer (because for each tree the 5 cross validation r2 should be created 5*50=250)

How can I create the two column or six column array for storing my estimation results?

Comment: which version of sklearn are you using? in v18, the Kfold code you are using is invalid.

Comment: Also you need to re think your while loop. you are starting from 1 and going till 49 only.

Comment: My scikit-learn version is 0.17. I think I can correct it putting in the np.linspace command parameter num=51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `while loop` wrong. Your current code only loops for `49` times. 
Also you are not doing `P_scores` appending correctly. Other than that the code is performing as expected.
You need to change the code as follows:

```
P_scores = []
z1 = 1

# This loop will execute 50 times
while z1 <= 50:
   clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=z1, random_state=1)
   clf.fit(X, Y)
   kf = KFold(len(X), n_folds=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
   R2 = cross_val_score(clf, X, Y, cv=kf, n_jobs=-1, scoring='r2')

   # This will append index z1 and scores for that index as a tuple to the P_scores array
   # Each R2 array will have 5 elements (number of folds)
   # So total 250 scores (as you wanted)
   P_scores.append((z1,R2))
   z1 += 1
print(P_scores)
```